# Are these parts of the ginger plant edible?

Tags: ginger

Are these tiny roots edible? My home grown ginger has lots of them and it seems a shame to throw them out if they're edible.

[image: anatomical painting of a ginger plant showing tiny roots at the bottom]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you can eat most of the rest of the plant, it is likely that they are edible.

Note that edible != palatable. I can't find any references indicating that they are eaten anywhere. It may be that they have a texture that is odd or are just not flavourful in any way.